# MATLAB error in ode45: must return a column vector

Tags: matlab, ode

I am getting this error in my code:

- **Error using odearguments (line 91)
  @(T,C)(C1.*((V1.*P_OPEN)+V2).*(CA_ER-C))-((V3.*(C.^2))/(C.^2+(K3^2)))
  must return a column vector.**

But in the MATLAB documentation there is an example [Example 3](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?s_tid=srchtitle#zmw57dd0e475194) where the vectors are given as input but it works just fine. Why is that I get an error in my code?
This is my code:

```
Ca_ER   = 10e-6; 
c0  = 2e-6;   
c1  = .185; 
v1  = 6; 
v2  = .11;
v3  = .09e6;
v4  = 1.2;
k3  = .1e-6;
a1 = 400e6;
a2 = 0.2e6;
a3 = 400e6;
a4 = 0.2e6;
a5 = 20e6;
b2 = .21;
d1 = 0.13e-6;
d2 = b2/a2;
d3 = 943.4e-9;
d4 = d1*d2/d3; 
d5 = 82.34e-9; 
IP= .5e-6; 
Ca=.001e-6:.01e-6:1e-6;
num=Ca.*IP.*d2;
deno= (Ca.*IP+ IP*d2+d1*d2+Ca.*d3).*(Ca+d5);
p_open=( num./deno).^3; %this is the vector input   
dc=@(t,c) (c1.*((v1.*p_open)+v2).*(Ca_ER-c))-((v3.*(c.^2))/(c.^2+(k3^2)));
[t,c]=ode45(dc,linspace(0, 100, 1000),.19e-6);
plot(t,c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly that.  `ode45` needs to return a column vector but your variable `Ca` is in fact a **row vector**.  Therefore, inside the anonymous function, all processing is done by a row vector and what is returned is a row vector and the error is thus produced.

The culprit is this statement:

```
Ca=.001e-6:.01e-6:1e-6;
```

The above syntax is declaring a row vector.  Therefore, to transform this into a column vector, simply take the transpose:

```
Ca=.001e-6:.01e-6:1e-6;
Ca = Ca.'; %// Transpose
```

Comment: I did the transpose and now i get this error:  **Error using odearguments (line 93)
@(T,C)(C1.*((V1.*P_OPEN)+V2).*(CA_ER-C))-((V3.*(C.^2))/(C.^2+(K3^2)))
returns a vector of length 100, but the length of
initial conditions vector is 1. The vector
returned by
@(T,C)(C1.*((V1.*P_OPEN)+V2).*(CA_ER-C))-((V3.*(C.^2))/(C.^2+(K3^2)))
and the initial conditions vector must have the
same number of elements.**

Comment: @nashynash - Look at your third argument of `ode45`.  That is required to be a vector, yet you made it a single value.  I don't know enough of your problem to comment... but MATLAB errors are pretty clear... it's very hard to misinterpret what they're saying.

Comment: By third argument, do you mean this **(CA_ER-C)**.  

  My aim is to generate a result shown by figure 4 in this [article](http://www.pnas.org/content/89/20/9895.full.pdf).